# Physical Interpretation of Flowrate Time Derivative of Incompressible Fluid in Variable Volume Vessel with Single Inlet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, medical-physics

I am an academic researcher who studies fluid mechanics of the left ventricle (the primary chamber of the heart that actually pumps blood to the rest of your body). The majority of my work focuses on analysis of intra-ventricular velocity fields as measured by phase-contrast MRI and subject-specific computational fluid dynamics models. However, I am also interested in idealised assessments of the ventricle that utilise measurements that are commonly made in a clinical setting.

Most of these more basic analysis utilise the temporal profile of ventricular volume $V(t)$ and its derivative $\dot{V}(t)$, where $V(t)$ is measured by image segmentation of MRI scans.

$\dot{V}(t)$ is interesting to examine because the ventricle has two valves, and only one of them is open at a time (unless something is very wrong). Consequently, $\dot{V}(t)$ is equal to the volume flowrate across either valve.

Comparing features of $\dot{V}(t)$ between a few subject groups I have data for has yielded some interesting results. So, I'd like to see if there's anything I can do by comparing the second derivative of volume $\ddot{V}(t)$.

However, I'm hoping to get some help building my physical intuition of the second derivative beyond it being the "flowrate acceleration." I suspect that the second time derivative of volume *should* be related to the inertia of the ventricle walls, at least in some idealised or averaged sense because the wall motion is highly non-uniform, and that I should be able to approximate some aggregate forces acting normal to the internal surface. However, I haven't been able to convince myself of anything concrete in this regard.

So! If anyone has some suggestions for how I might use the second time derivative of volume to get at something interesting, particularly related to the net (normal) forces acting on the ventricular walls, I would be very grateful.

As a final note, the ventricle is often geometrically idealised as a half-prolate spheroid/spheroidal shell. So, provided that any geometric assumptions need to be made, I think this is a reasonable shape to use. However, to get things started, any shape that has a clear axial component, such as a circular cylinder, is likely a reasonable first approximation.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Would you please consider taking an initial shot at formulating such a model?  You can make it as oversimplified as you desire, as long as it includes most of the important physical mechanisms.